# Reportlab - Unicode characters appear as boxes in unicode-supported font

Tags: python, unicode, reportlab

Trying to use reportlab through python 3 to write a document that includes macrons (ā ē ī ō ū), but the macrons are showing up as boxes (■). The document is written in Arial font -- but if I open up the file in a word processor to check the font, the boxes are in 'Segoe UI Symbol' font.

For importing in Arial as a font that supports a broad range of unicode characters (which seems to have worked):

```
import reportlab.rl_config
reportlab.rl_config.warnOnMissingFontGlyphs = 0
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Arial', 'Arial.ttf'))
```

I also import a dictionary through json, looking something like this when I open the json file in notepad:

```
{"example1":"b\u0101s"}
```

The program reads and writes this dictionary:

```
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Spacer
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
doc = SimpleDocTemplate("hello.pdf")
Story = [Spacer(1,2*inch)]
style = styles["Normal"]
with open('CompDict.json','r') as f:
        m_dic=json.load(f)
for key,value in m_dic:
     p=Paragraph(key+":"+value,style)
     Story.append(p)
doc.build(Story)
```

The outcome should be a pdf with `example1:bās` but instead comes out as `example1:b■s`

Comment: Just an observation: The JSON snippet you show isn't valid JSON (which requires double quotes). But that's probably not related to your problem.

Comment: Python 2.x or 3?

Comment: I'm using python 3.6

Answer (score 1):

```
#Here I am writing chunks of code, hope you will understand

from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph, SimpleDocTemplate, Spacer  
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle   
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_CENTER,TA_JUSTIFY       
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics      
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont   
from reportlab.lib.fonts import addMapping

pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('devaNagri', 'NotoSerifDevanagari.ttf')) # devaNagri is a folder located in **/usr/share/fonts/truetype** and 'NotoSerifDevanagari.ttf' file you just download it from https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-deva and move to devaNagri folder.

addMapping('devaNagri', 0, 0, 'NotoSerifDevanagari') #devnagri is a folder name and NotoSerifDevanagari is file name 

style = getSampleStyleSheet()   
style.add(ParagraphStyle(name="ParagraphTitle", alignment=TA_JUSTIFY, fontName="devaNagri")) # after mapping fontName define your folder name.   
paragraph = Paragraph('your unicode string', style["ParagraphTitle"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Find your character under this link:

[UTF-8 encoding table and Unicode characters](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=128&number=128&utf8=string-literal&unicodeinhtml=hex)

1. Go to (utf-in literal) row of the table.
2. You will see some: `\xc3\x85` like characters. Choose your character...
3. Then for text output, in your code type something like :

   `Canvas.drawString(x,y,'\xc3\x85')` =>  and it will print `Å` ...

So you have to change your dictionary items to UTF-8 LITERALS because it will not understand `"b\u0101s"`Unicode, which there are many ways to do so ...

best regards